# Log errors of event receiver azure hosted office 365 apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, app, azure

I have one app for Office 365 with Azure hosted. I have some code in my app event receiver.

I am able to deploy my app in app catalog but not able to add it to site collection due to installation errors. Inspecting errors it says some exception occurred in event receiver code.

Now I want to log the actual exception and figure out what is going wrong. What will be the best way to log this?

Btw I have access to Azure, SharePoint online and office 365 admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything you like but you'll have to implement it yourself. Personally I'd use Azure Table Storage but you can use SQL, text files, SharePoint lists, or whatever you want.

If your code is running in Azure you can also debug your code directly by clicking "Attach Debugger" in your Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio (you need the Azure tools for VS installed to do this).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but on this many clients are using our apps from same azure server. Attaching debugger will pause others request also. And it is difficult to debug when multiple request are processing.

Comment: Well, no, you never debug in production.